# how to create video using mediaCodec?

Tags: android, video, android-mediacodec

Is it possible to create video of series of Images present on SdCard using MediaCodec? if yes, can anyone share me the link?
I want to import images from sdCard and create video from those images, any suggestions???
I want to do this programmatically. I've tried using jcodec library but the process is very slow and I want to fasten up a little bit more.
Is there any chances that MediaCodec can do that in my ADT and in much faster way.

Importing images from SdCard --> making a good quality .mp4 video (faster than jcodec way).

Comment: It's certainly possible to modify the bigflake.com / Grafika samples to use still images instead of generated content or camera input.  There is currently no sample code on those sites that does what you want though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try INDE Media Pack - https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials

It has transcoding\remuxing functionality as MediaComposer class and several sample effects like JpegSubstituteEffect - it shows how substitute video frame by a picture from jpg file. You can take black video as a refefence and put images on it with a possibility to set duration, add audio track with help of audio effect etc.

[image]

Comment: What if I've to code the same thing in my ADT...??? I want to try it programmatically and wants to find out if this is possible using MediaCodedc in ADT.

Comment: MediaPack is like SDK library, you can use it in your app, for your convince it has a sample code which shows how to use it. Inside it uses MediaCodec so works fast